# Units of variables within the error function

Tags: units

For the error function, erf$((x-\mu)/\sigma)$, if $x$ has unit of length, what are the units of $\mu$, $\sigma$? Is there a standard for these type of functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac {x-\mu}{\sigma}$ must be dimensionless so they all have to have the same unit.

Answer (score 2):

The argument of the $\text{erf}$ function, $(x-\mu)/\sigma$,
needs to be just a number (i.e. without any unit).

Therefore, to accomplish this, since $x$ has unit of length, also $\mu$ and $\sigma$ need to have unit of length.